# angular.js loading div showing only once on each route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Html

```
<div id="loading" ng-controller="LoadingCtrl" ng-show="isViewLoading">Loading</div>
```

JS

```
app.controller('LoadingCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.isViewLoading = false;
  $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
    $scope.isViewLoading = true;
  });
  $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    $scope.isViewLoading = false;
  });

});
```

Loading div shows only on the first time that I call some route. If I call this route again div is not showing. What's wrong?

Edit: it stops updating isViewLoading variable when I call some route second time

Comment: Maybe because you dont have enough time to see the div. Try with Breakpoint

Comment: It can't be problem because first time I click on each route I see it.

Comment: I think you should try it anyway : the template may be added in cache so it's faster after the first time => you don't see it.

Comment: Alright I did it,  it's not showing but it's updating isViewLoading variable

Comment: The first time the controller is not initialize and you have more time to see the loading. The other times use the old controller, and maybe all happens in the same digest, then nothing happen.

Comment: No. I have 10 links, when I click all those 10 links first time I SEE loading div, when I click any of them second(third,..) time loading is not showing